# Run Process builder script as another user

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I run the su command within my instance as

```
su - myuser
```

But I am not sure how to run the script as this user

```
String cmd = script.getScriptPath() + "/" + script.getScriptName();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process p = pb.start();
// wait for script to end before output
p.waitFor();
exitCode = p.exitValue();
```

Would really appreciate advice on how to do so, thank you

Edit: I start from root so I normally do not need to give a password when doing it from inside the instance, I assume I wouldn't need to via process builder?

Comment: That's what sudo is for.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this :)

```
command = new String[] {"su", "-sl", userName, "-c", scriptName};
```

The -l parameter uses the environment variables of the given user, and then just send that into process builder